# с++: массив в качестве параметра по умолчанию

Tags: c++, функции, параметры, передача-параметров

подскажите пожалуйста, а то голова что-то не варит уже, как реализовать следующую вещь:

есть функция, которая в качестве параметра принимает указатель:

```
void func(int* data)
```

можно ли в качестве параметра по умолчанию указать статический массив с заданным кол-вом элементов, что-то типа такого

```
void func(int* data = (int*)int[1024])
```

а было бы еще лучше, если бы по умолчанию указывался заполненный нулями массив

конечно это можно сделать через std::vector и ссылку или через собственный класс, но можно ли как-то сделать через простые типы?

Comment: После всех обсуждений, простите уж, но постановка вопроса... ну, чтоб не обидеть - абсолютно неоднозначная.

Comment: @Harry, чуть подправил, интересно в первую очередь было можно ли указать статический массив в качестве параметра по умолчанию, вернее указатель на статический массив, который бы существовал только в заданной функции

Comment: В **этой формулировке** лучший ответ - @AlexGlebe.

Comment: по поводу статического массива не будет никакой разницы, будете всегда обнулять *его* или *свежий* массив в стеке. Свежий массив в стеке кушать не просит. (*ни* памяти *ни* работы).

Answer (score 7):

Всё очень просто.

```
void func(int* data){
 ..}

void func(void){
   int data[1024]={};
   func(data); }
```

Аргументы по-умолчанию это плохой стиль. Проще так.

Comment: Преимущество аргументов по умолчанию в code reuse. Если у вас будут две функции с одним и тем-же кодомю... Я думаю вы понимаете, чем это чревато, когда ты что-то меняешь.

Comment: Такая обёртка просто необходима например, если аргументу будет выделена память с помощью `new`. Тогда в конце уже проставляется освобождение памяти и всё пучком. Просто и понятно. @Rivand

Comment: про какую обёртку вы говорите? Если вы про RAII, то тут вам нужен std::unique_ptr, но тогда проще сразу использовать std::vector. В вашем коде никаких обёрток нет.

Comment: Функция `void func(void)` - это обёртка для вызова функции `void func(int* data)` @Rivand

Comment: ну поскольку массивы небольшие, то они могут быть статически размещены в коде, по идее можно сделать - передавать указатель который по умолчанию `nullptr`, внутри функции разместить статический массив и если указатель нулевой, то брать указатель на этот массив иначе брать указатель на массив, указанный в параметре - хотя конечно это не однострочное решение :)

Comment: @AlexGlebe Ок, тогда я вас просто не понял. Для меня обёртка это либо паттерн враппер либо RAII. `void func(void)` - для меня обычная перегрузка. Я не совсем понимаю, что она оборачивает. Но это вопрос терминологии, который несуществен в данном вопросе.

Comment: Трабл у статического массива, что нужно будет постоянно обнулять элементы вручную. И при каких-то условиях (если аргумент NULL). Куча лишних проблем. @Zhihar

Comment: почему же - вроде как при каждом заходе в функцию если внутри int arr[100] = {0} гарантируется, что он будет нулевым - скорее всего компилятор туда memset вставит

Comment: Если массив статический, `static int arr[1024]={0};` то обнуление будет только при **первом** вызове. Во втором, всё вручную нужно обнулять.

Comment: Я отметил обе ответа, но  вариант перегрузки  лучше с точки зрения очевидности.

Answer (score 5):

Если вам принципиально значение по умолчанию в интерфейсе, то используйте std::array.

`void func(int* data = std::array<int, 1024>().data())`

Но нормальным решением будет ставить значение по умолчанию `nullptr` и уже в самом теле функции создавать массив, если data == nullptr.